# Объясните решение задачи по sql

Tags: sql

[image]

почему здесь используется MAX и почему группировка идет по id

Comment: группировка по t.id это группировка по учителям, зачем пропустили строки через MAX теряюсь в догадках, можно было просто вывести или сделать сортировку после группировки по t.id

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 0):

t.id = это уникальный индентификатор учителя. Запрос группирует все данные по t.id, то есть по учителю, и для каждой группы подсчитывает и выводит количество занятий "COUNT(s.subject)".

MAX используется для того, чтобы вывести значения из полей first_name и last_name. Группировка требует, чтобы в результате были только поля, по которым происходит группировка, или агрегатные функции вроде COUNT или MAX. То есть нужно однозначно определить, что именно выводить. В группе с одним id может быть не одна запись, и откуда именно брать first_name и last_name? Вот функция MAX точно и определяет, что нужно взять максимальное из значений. Понятно, что в группе по одному id first_name и last_name будут одинаковые. Можно вместо MAX написать MIN, будет то же самое - попробуйте.

Можно было бы включить first_name и last_name в группировку вместе с id и тогда их можно просто вывести без агрегатной функции, ведь их значение определено. Результат будет тем же самым:

```
SELECT t.first_name, t.last_name, COUNT(s.subject)
...
GROUP BY t.first_name, t.last_name, id
```

Comment: Подзапросом их надо включать, тогда никаких лишних операций делаться не будет.

Comment: `select … from Teacher as t left join (select s.teacher, count(s.subject) as amount_classes) s on t.id = s.teacher`